# Are there books for narcissists on topic of self healing?

Tags: personality, personality-disorder

Search in amazon reveals a lot of books around topic of being narcissist wife, handling narcissist, leaving narcissist etc.

Are there any (worthy) books for narcissists about narcissism and self healing?

Maybe there are also separate books for grandiose and covert subtypes.